# How to use docker to spin up postgres database

Tags: postgresql, tcp, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to have my app code communicate with my postgres db, each of which is running in separate container. However, whenever I attempt to access my db, I keep getting **"dial tcp 172.19.0.3:5432: getsockopt: connection refused"** which I understand to mean that there is nothing listening on port 5432. But I don't understand how that could be since docker reported no errors starting up my app server or postgres server.

```
version: '2'
services:
  postgres:
    restart: 'no'
    image: mhatch/eventcliq_pgdb
    volumes_from:
     - data
    ports:
     - "5432"
    environment:
     - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=TEST_PG_PWD

 data:
  restart: 'no'
  image: postgres:9.5.1
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/postgresql
    - /etc/postgresql
    - /var/log/postgresql
  command: "true"

  api:
    restart: 'no'
    build: .
    environment:
      - ENV=dev
    image: mhatch/eventcliq-api
    ports:
      - "80:3001"
    links:
      - postgres:db
```

[image: successful docker-compose up]

[image: docker ps]

[image: api reporting socket error[![][3]]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpdak.png)

Note: the pgAdmin error results when trying to connect to 0.0.0.0:32793. The x'd connection is to a different saved and working server (which I was not trying to connect to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to test my original setup on a different computer and things seem to be working alright. It appears my original issue is restricted to my desktop and there just may be some networking configuration issues I need to resolve on that machine.

Answer (score 0):

Posting your docker-compose file would help answering your question better. Nevertheless, I could give it a try looking at your screenshots.

In your docker-compose file change the ports entry - 5432 or - 5432:5432 to

```
ports:
  - "127.0.0.1:5432:5432"
```

and give a go. The issue seems to be with IPv6 vs IPv4. with this change you should be able to connect to postgres.

Comment: thanks for the response, but i don't think i want to hardcode the port-mapping.

Comment: That is not hard coding the port mapping. 127.0.0.1 is just the localhost. If you don't give this, the network interface of docker would treat it as IPV6 address and hence would not be able to find the service.